# Common modifications for all actions in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So here is the problem, I need some modifications to always to be done after each and every action **except one.** So in order to achieve this I have done the following. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'AddCheckboxJson': {
      return ReducerWrapper({ ...state,objCheckBox:action.payload  });
    }
    case 'insertAt':return ReducerWrapper({
      ...state,objCheckBox:{...state.objCheckBox,
        Values:insertAt(action.payload.index,action.payload.entry,"iDisplayOrder",state.objCheckBox)
      }
    })
    case 'INSERT_ABOVE': 
      return ReducerWrapper({
        ...state, objRadio: {
          ...state.objRadio,
          Values: action.payload
        }
      })

    case 'INSERT_BELOVE': 
      return ReducerWrapper({
        ...state, objRadio: {
          ...state.objRadio,
          Values: action.payload
        }
      }),
    case 'REPLACE':return { ...action.payload }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Here the function **ReducerWrapper** does the common modification

```
export const ReducerWrapper = State => {
   return {...State,
    //modifications done here
   }
}
```

Comment: if all those modifications are common, why not doing in the starting of the function itself?

Comment: for 1 action I dont want this to happen. the replace action and the default

Comment: for that, along with action object, you can pass a extra bool to check whether modification is required or not, can use that bool for condition. or for all the cases where you want to perform modification prepare a obj first, then outside of switch do the modification with that obj.

Comment: I thought of that, but they done want any component code to be changed. So I guess under the circumstances this is the best approach.

Comment: do you want this through all reducers or just one ?

Comment: I need to change only  this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a lot simpler than it probably seems, just return for the two scenarios you *don't* want to apply the additional state i.e.

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'AddCheckboxJson': {
      state = { 
        ...state, 
        objCheckBox: action.payload 
      };
    }
    case 'insertAt': {
      state = {
        ...state,
        objCheckBox:{
          ...state.objCheckBox,
          Values: insertAt(
            action.payload.index, 
            action.payload.entry, 
            "iDisplayOrder", 
            state.objCheckBox
          )
        }
      }
    }
    case 'INSERT_ABOVE': { 
      state = {
        ...state, 
        objRadio: {
          ...state.objRadio,
          Values: action.payload
        }
      }
    }
    // presumably this should be INSERT_BELOW?
    case 'INSERT_BELOVE': {
      state = {
        ...state, 
        objRadio: {
          ...state.objRadio,
          Values: action.payload
        }
      }
    },
    // return the state early in both these scenarios
    case 'REPLACE': return { ...action.payload }
    default: return state;
  }

  // run additional state change
  return ReducerWrapper(state);
};
```